# How can I open file explorer to have a user select a file in go

Tags: go

I want to pop open file explorer and have a user select a file and then capture the filepath they select. Similar to the way you might upload a file in chrome where you browse your computer with file explorer and then select something to input.

Comment: Are you trying to develop an UI using go?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [fyne-io](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne) or [zenity](https://github.com/ncruces/zenity).